# How to reverse a singly-linked list and convert it to a vector?

Tags: data-structures, rust

While writing the A* algorithm, I tried to reverse a singly-linked list of actions and pack it into `Vec`.

Here's the structure for my singly-linked list:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

struct FrontierElem<A> {
    prev: Option<Rc<FrontierElem<A>>>,
    action: A,
}
```

My first thought was to `push` actions into `Vec` then reverse the vector:

```
fn rev1<A>(fel: &Rc<FrontierElem<A>>) -> Vec<A>
where
    A: Clone,
{
    let mut cur = fel;
    let mut ret = Vec::new();
    while let Some(ref prev) = cur.prev {
        ret.push(cur.action.clone());
        cur = prev;
    } // First action (where cur.prev==None) is ignored by design
    ret.as_mut_slice().reverse();
    ret
}
```

I didn't find the `SliceExt::reverse` method at the time, so I proceeded to the second plan: fill the vector from the end to the start. I didn't find a way to do that safely.

```
/// Copies action fields from single-linked list to vector in reverse order.
/// `fel` stands for first element
fn rev2<A>(fel: &Rc<FrontierElem<A>>) -> Vec<A>
where
    A: Clone,
{
    let mut cnt = 0usize;
    // First pass. Let's find a length of list `fel`
    {
        let mut cur = fel;
        while let Some(ref prev) = cur.prev {
            cnt = cnt + 1;
            cur = prev;
        }
    } // Lexical scoping to unborrow `fel`

    // Second pass. Create and fill `ret` vector
    let mut ret = Vec::<A>::with_capacity(cnt);
    {
        let mut idx = cnt - 1;
        let mut cur = fel;
        // I didn't find safe and fast way to populate vector from the end to the beginning.
        unsafe {
            ret.set_len(cnt); //unsafe. vector values aren't initialized
            while let Some(ref prev) = cur.prev {
                ret[idx] = cur.action.clone();
                idx = idx - 1;
                cur = prev;
            }
        }
        assert_eq!(idx, std::usize::MAX);
    } // Lexical scoping to make `fel` usable again
    ret
}
```

While I was writing this, it occurred to me that I can also implement `Iterator` for the linked list and then use `rev` and `from_iter` to create a vector. Alas, this requires significant overhead, as I must implement `DoubleEndedIterator` trait for `rev` to work.

At this point my question seems trivial, but I post it in hope that it will be of some use.

Benchmark:

```
running 2 tests
test bench_rev1 ... bench:   1537061 ns/iter (+/- 14466)
test bench_rev2 ... bench:   1556088 ns/iter (+/- 17165)
```

Comment: It’s OK to post something like this as a question and then answer it, but you need to follow the appropriate forms for this site: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill the vector, then reverse it using `.as_mut_slice().reverse()`.

```
fn rev1<A>(fel: &Rc<FrontierElem<A>>) -> Vec<A>
where
    A: Clone,
{
    let mut cur = fel;
    let mut ret = Vec::new();
    while let Some(ref prev) = cur.prev {
        ret.push(cur.action.clone());
        cur = prev;
    } // First action (where cur.prev==None) is ignored by design
    ret.as_mut_slice().reverse();
    ret
}
```